# How to run an Express API via Firebase Cloud Functions locally?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a standard REST API using Express, exposed via a Firebase Cloud Function.

```js
const api = express()

api.get('/test', (req, res) => res.status(403).json({ "REASON": "UNAUTHORIZED" }))

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(api)
```

**Remote**

When I deploy it and send `GET https://<remote>/api/test` via Postman I get `403 { "REASON": "UNAUTHORIZED" }` as expected.

**Local**

When I run `firebase emulators:start --only functions` to serve these functions locally and test them, I do see `functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/.../api` in my terminal, but when I send `GET http://localhost:5001/.../api/test` via Postman I get `200 Not Found`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have reproduction steps for something with the Firebase emulator suite that isn't working the way you expect, I suggest filing an issue on the Firebase CLI GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: It was indeed a defect in the Firebase CLI, it seems to be fixed in the latest version (7.13.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a defect in the Firebase CLI, it seems to be fixed in the latest version (7.13.1)

Installed the latest version using: `npm install -g firebase-tools@latest`

> Note: it did require me to update to compatible version of `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin` as well.